# Error - the program is not giving output while calling the print method

Tags: c#

This is a simple program I created - one table class, one main class. In the table class I created a print method which simply outputs my name. From the main class I am calling the print method but not getting the output.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{

    class table
    {

        public static void print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("My name is prithvi-raj chouhan");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            table t = new table();
            t.print();  // Error the program is not giving output while calling the print method

        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the function you are calling is static.
Use this syntax

```
public static void Main()
         { 
            table.print();     
         }
```

Quote from MSDN:-

> A static method, field, property, or event is callable on a class even
>   when no instance of the class has been created. **If any instances of
>   the class are created, they cannot be used to access the static
>   member**. Only one copy of static fields and events exists, and static
>   methods and properties can only access static fields and static
>   events. Static members are often used to represent data or
>   calculations that do not change in response to object state; for
>   instance, a math library might contain static methods for calculating
>   sine and cosine.

Comment: thanks . can you explain a little between static and instance method.if i am right these are the two used for methods.thanks in advance

Comment: You can take a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.80).aspx , it has got lot more things for you to learn.

Answer (score 1):

`print` is a `static` method, so call it as a static method:

```
public static void Main()
{
    table.print();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
           table.Print();

        }
    }
```

Print(); is a static method so you dont need to instantiate a new Table object in order to access it's methods

Answer (score 0):

You are calling print() as an instance method but it is static. Try to remove the static keyword from the method.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add a `Console.ReadLine();` after `table.print();`.

**UPDATE:**

Missed the part with static, now corrected.

Comment: Eh, could @downvoter please explain? Glad it helped Geek, please vote on all the answers that are helping you and check the one that helped you the most as the correct answer.